# Unable to sign text block with Private Key

Tags: public-key-encryption, signing, private-key, sha256, public-key

I am trying to create a digital signature of a load of clipboard text. I am:

1. Creating a SHA-256 hash of the plain text.
2. Encrypting this hash with my PRIVATE key.
3. Attempting to decrypt this with my PUBLIC key.

I'm doing this as I am of the understanding that anything signed with my PRIVATE key can be decrypted with my PUBLIC - such as this for verification?  Is this wrong?

I'm encrypting the hash with these methods:

```
                public static string EncryptText(string text, int keySize, string publicKey)
            {
                var encrypted = Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text), keySize, publicKey);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
            }

            public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, int keySize, string publicKeyXml)
            {
                if (data == null || data.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Data are empty", "data");
                int maxLength = GetMaxDataLength(keySize);
                if (data.Length > maxLength) throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Maximum data length is {0}", maxLength), "data");
                if (!IsKeySizeValid(keySize)) throw new ArgumentException("Key size is not valid", "keySize");
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(publicKeyXml)) throw new ArgumentException("Key is null or empty", "publicKeyXml");

                using (var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keySize))
                {
                    provider.FromXmlString(publicKeyXml);
                    return provider.Encrypt(data, OptimalAsymmetricEncryptionPadding);
                }
            }
```

but passing my `PRIVATE KEY` down instead of my `PUBLIC KEY`.

Then to verify the signature, I am using:

```
                public static string DecryptText(string privateKey, int keySize, string text)
            {
                var decrypted = Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(text), keySize, privateKey);
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);
            }

            public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data, int keySize, string publicAndPrivateKeyXml)
            {
                if (data == null || data.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Data are empty", "data");
                if (!IsKeySizeValid(keySize)) throw new ArgumentException("Key size is not valid", "keySize");
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(publicAndPrivateKeyXml)) throw new ArgumentException("Key is null or empty", "publicAndPrivateKeyXml");

                using (var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keySize))
                {
                    provider.FromXmlString(publicAndPrivateKeyXml);
                    return provider.Decrypt(data, OptimalAsymmetricEncryptionPadding);
                }
            }
```

but passing down my `PUBLIC KEY` rather than the `PRIVATE KEY`. At this point, I am getting an error "Key does not exist".

I'm presuming this is the case because the `PRIVATE KEY` contains the relevant key information for the `PUBLIC KEY` so it can decode this one-way.

How can I sign a block of text in this way that allows me to distribute a signature with it, that can be decrypted by anybody who knows my `PUBLIC KEY`?

Answer (score 0):

After much trawling, I found this page:
http://juzzbott.com.au/blog/signing-and-verifying-data-within-csharp